# Group and Transpose in R

Tags: r, group-by, transpose

I have this dataset [enter image description here][1] (column names are Cancer & Frequency)

I 'm hoping to have the output have  CNS-PiloAstro and Eso-AdenoCa  as the column name and listing the frequency below. How do I group them by "Cancer" and transpose it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoeME.png
Thakn you for your help!

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

This sums the frequencies and has the cancers as the column names.

```
cns=c(1,4,1,1,3,1,2,6,5,1,2,1,2,3,4)
eso=c(125,131,80,69,34,204,123,137,66,112,113,126,125,73,218,130,57,314)
df=data.frame(cancer=c(rep("CNS-PiloAstro", length(cns)), rep("Eso-AdenoCa", length(eso))), freq=c(cns, eso))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1=group_by(df, cancer) %>% summarize(across(freq ,sum))
pivot_wider(df1, names_from=cancer, values_from=freq)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `CNS-PiloAstro` `Eso-AdenoCa`
            <dbl>         <dbl>
1              37          2237
```

Or if you want to keep the individual frequencies, you can do this:

```
df2=data.frame()
cancers=unique(df$cancer)
for (i in 1:length(cancers)) {
  val=filter(df, cancer==cancers[i]) %>% select(freq) %>% unlist()
  tmp=data.frame(val)
  colnames(tmp)=cancers[i]
  if (i==1) {
    df2=tmp
    next
  }
  if (nrow(tmp) < nrow(df2)) {
    extra=nrow(df2)-nrow(tmp)
    for (j in 1:extra) {
      tmp[nrow(tmp)+1,]=NA
    }
  } else if (nrow(tmp) > nrow(df2)) {
    extra=nrow(tmp)-nrow(df2)
    for (j in 1:extra) {
      df2[nrow(df2)+1,]=rep(NA, ncol(df2))
    }
  }
  df2=cbind(df2, tmp)
}
df2

       CNS-PiloAstro Eso-AdenoCa
freq1              1         125
freq2              4         131
freq3              1          80
freq4              1          69
freq5              3          34
freq6              1         204
freq7              2         123
freq8              6         137
freq9              5          66
freq10             1         112
freq11             2         113
freq12             1         126
freq13             2         125
freq14             3          73
freq15             4         218
16                NA         130
17                NA          57
18                NA         314
```